# Activity diagram object flow usage

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have this piece of diagram:

[image]

I would like to ask, if it is OK that two transisions goes to **Confirm request**. Is it also OK that two transition goes from **Choose food**? One transition is object flow, one is control flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object flow is shown with action pins sending and accepting the object.

[image]

Also an object flow with Information Flows realized is shown like above where `Chosen food` directly links to the classifier.

You "can" use an `ObjectFlow` like you did. But it introduces a bit of ambiguity since you can not distinguish an `ObjectFlow` from a `ControlFlow` as they have the same shape. So this is what I'd recommend to give a clear picture.

On p. 379 of the specs you find

> An object flow is notated by an arrowed line. In Figure 15.9, upper right, the two object flow arrows denote a single object flow edge between two pins in the underlying model, as shown in the lower middle of the figure. (See other Pin notations in sub clause 16.2. The specific notational variant used shall be preserved when the diagram is interchanged, see Annex B.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but why is in Visual Paradigm option for "Object Node"? Is really my diagram bad?

Comment: But is not there a problem that two arrows go to one state in my example?

Comment: No, since the one is a control flow and the other is an object flow. You send food to the `Confirm request` action and it piles up at its input pin. Once the control flow reaches it, it will process the food in some way. Buon appetito.

Comment: N.B. I'd rather model the `[choose more]` simply inside the `Choose food` (there is no plural for food, is there?). That would make the flow simpler to draw.